# How can I insert a line with a new line appended to a file using sed on mac?

Tags: shell, sed

I want to insert a text line, lets say "hello" to the 3rd line of the file. And there should be a new line appended:

```
1st
2nd
Hello

3rd
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Very straightforward with `awk`:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

```
$ awk 'NR==3{print "hello\n"}1' file
1
2
hello

3
4
5
6
```

Where `NR` is the line number. You can set it to any number you wish to insert text to.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be sed?

```
head -2 infile ; echo Hello ; echo ; tail +3 infile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed '3s/^/Hello\n\n/' file.txt
1st
2nd
Hello

3rd
```

The `3` at the beginning of the `sed` command specifies that the command should be applied to line 3 only.  Thus, the command, `3s/^/Hello\n\n/`, substitutes in "Hello" and two new lines to the beginning (`^` matches the beginning of a line) of line 3.  Otherwise, the file is left unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '3 i\
Hello\
' YopurFile
```

Insert following line (preceded by `\`) at line 3